# Is there any way to match similar match in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have a elastic search big document

I am searching with below query

```
{"size": 1000, "query": {"query_string": {"query": "( string1 )"}}}
```

Let say my string1 = Product, If some one accident type prduct some one forgot to `o`

Is there any way to search for that also

`{"size": 1000, "query": {"query_string": {"query": "( prdct )"}}}` also has to return result of prdct + product

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Comment: thank u for accepting the answer :) It would be great if you can upvote the answer as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) that returns documents that contain terms similar to the search term. Refer this [blog](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-optimization-fuzziness-performance) to get detailed explanation of fuzzy queries.**

Since,you have more edit distance to match `prdct`. Fuzziness parameter can be defined as :

```
0, 1, 2

0..2 = Must match exactly

3..5 = One edit allowed

More than 5 = Two edits allowed
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "title":"product"
}
{
  "title":"prdct"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "title": {
                "value": "prdct",
                "fuzziness":15,
                "transpositions":true,
                 "boost": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 3.465736,
        "_source": {
          "title": "prdct"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-index1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.0794415,
        "_source": {
          "title": "product"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Note that `"fuzziness":15` will be capped at the value 2 for any Elasticsearch version of the last couple of years. Your description of `AUTO` for fuzziness is correct, but misses how to set it; see [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness).

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this problem:

- [Suggestions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html) (did you mean X instead).
- [Fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) (edits from your original search term).
- Partial matching with autocomplete (if someone types "pr" and you provide the available search terms, they can click on the correct results right away) or n-grams (matching groups of letters).

All of those have tradeoffs in index / search overhead as well as the classic precision / recall problem.